# Android C2DM server send message

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I try to test c2dm app. 
I have sign up for Android Cloud to Device Messaging.
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html

For example:

Contact email *
Email address we should contact when you've been whitelisted:
aaa@gmail.com

Role account email *
Google Account ID that will be used for sending messages to C2DM:
bbb@gmail.com

I register from my app and sender id (bbb@gmail.com) to c2dm service and i get registration_id.

After that my third party server must get ClientLogin authentication using email and password. From which email? The whitelisted email (aaa@gmail.com) or sender id (bbb@gmail.com)?? I try both email and from this process i got authorization_id.

But when i use the registration_id and authorization_id to send message to C2DM Server, i got response codes 401 Unauthorize. I use authorization_id from whitelisted email (aaa@gmail.com) and sender id (bbb@gmail.com) but none worked.

What could be the problem?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After i try again it's working now, my third party server must use sender id (bbb@gmail.com) to get ClientLogin authentication and from this process i got authorization_id.

And i use the registration_id and authorization_id to send message to C2DM Server. My device receive the message.

Comment: please post the code for receiving notification. I alse get the registration id and token. and using php, i am sending message to c2dm server. but i dont know how to recieve thje notification...

Comment: you can see the example  JumpNote and Chrome To Phone. http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/  http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/